# Rotate transform on SVG works on all browsers except IE - https://codepen.io/linamary/pen/zgWvoN

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, setinterval, css-transforms, rotatetransform

I need the rotate transform to work on IE. Right now, when I click on the pink region, the visible region just jumps instead of gradually moving.

```
 test1.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(75, 500, 500)");
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is the codepen link - https://codepen.io/linamary/pen/zgWvoN

Comment: I try to test the issue with IE 11 and it looks like issue is not about rotate transform because another example of rotate transform is working fine in IE. I notice that there is 1 error in the console. It can be possible that this error is causing the issue. Ref: https://i.postimg.cc/sDTb2G92/234.png